# Data is not updated after changes in the Sanity Studio

Tags: reactjs, next.js, sanity, groq

I am quite new to Sanity v3 + Next.js v13. Everything works great on my test site, but I have a problem when I update a document (project) or add a new one in the Sanity Studio – these changes are not updated on the pages. I am still on localhost. I want to see the changes right after they are made. If I update the query and save the file, the elements will be updated. Is it some kind of caching issue?

My example is here:

```
export async function getProjects(): Promise<Project[]> {
  return createClient(clientConfig).fetch(
    groq`*[_type=="project"]|order(_createdAt desc){
    _id,
    _createdAt,
    name,
    "slug": slug.current,
    "image": image.asset->url,
    url,
    content
  }`
  );
}

*** exported clientConfig ***
const config = {
  projectId: "xxxxxx",
  dataset: "production",
  apiVersion: "v1",
};

export default config;
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem, you can use the Route Segment Config options to opt out of caching for a specific route segment as follows.

```
const Projects = async () => {
         // component code
}

export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";

export default Projects;
```

This will make our page dynamically rendered at the request time.
Additional information is available on this [link](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching#opting-out-1) from the official NextJS documentation.

Answer (score 0):

To show new projects, you will have to do the following:

Above both of your export default functions, add the following:

```js
export const revalidate = 60
```

Comment: Can you expand a little more on what this does, maybe reference some documentation?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You have option for **revalidation** in **next-sanity**. for **time-based**: you could do this:

```
    export async function getProjects(): Promise<Project[]> {
      return createClient(clientConfig).fetch(
         <groq-query>,
         {},
         { next : { revalidate : 3600 });
    }
```

You can find more on the **Cache revalidation section** of the next-sanity npm page.